# How to display a div only for certain urls in react js

Tags: reactjs

How to make a component visible only for certain urls. I need to display a search box when user clicks on a link, i know this can be achieved using event listeners. but the issue is, if user types the url in browser search bar navigated to by the button, the search box doesn't show up.

[image]

when on the **Users** page, the search box has to be displayed and when user clicks or navigates to **New**, the search box has to be hidden.

Below is the code :

```
import React from "react";
import { Button } from "./Button";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { Form, FormControl } from "react-bootstrap";
import "./Navbar.css";
import "./Home.css";

function Home() {
  return (
    <div className="dashboard-btns">
      <div className="x">
        <Link to="/users" className="btn-mobile">
          <Button buttonStyle="btn--secondary">Users</Button>
        </Link>
        <Link to="/new" className="btn-mobile">
          <Button buttonStyle="btn--secondary">New</Button>
        </Link>

        <Form inline>
          <FormControl id="search" type="text" placeholder="users" />
          <Link to="/users" className="btn-mobile">
            <Button
              buttonStyle="btn--secondary"
              buttonSize="btn--small--search"
              type="submit"
            >
              Search
            </Button>
          </Link>
        </Form>
      </div>
     
    </div>
  );
}

export default Home;
```

Still learning Frontend development. Any help is really appreciated

Answer (score 3):

One of the ways is you can use `Location` to match the path and hide/show it. import `useLocation` from `react-router-dom`. and then use the conditional rendering

```
const location = useLocation();   
{location.pathname.includes("users") && <Button>...</Button>}
```